# Selecting specific id in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marias_products WHERE product_id = $id ");
      $projects = array();
      while($rowrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $projects[] = $rowrow;
      }
      foreach ($projects as $project) {
          $resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id LIKE '%".$id."%'");
           while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultq))
            { 
                $qwerty=$rows['qtyleft'];
            }   
              if ($qwerty!=0)
              {     
                 // echo '<input type="text" name="pizasize" value="'.$project['product_size_name'].'"/>';
                   echo '<input hidden type="text" name="idd" value="'.$project['mp_id'].'"/>';

                    echo '<tr>';
                      echo '<td>'.$project['product_size_name'].'</td>';
                      echo '<td>'.$project['product_price'].'</td>';
                      echo '<td>'.$project['mp_id'].'</td>';
                      echo '<td>'.'<input name="but" type="image" value="'.$project['mp_id'].'" src="images/button.png" />'.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
              }
              else
              {
                 echo 'not available';
              }
        }
```

I'm having a problem with getting the selected '`mp_id`' inside in foreach loop. What happen is that once I select by clicking the button. I've selected the last ID of the entire table. Hope someone could help. Ty. Just learning PHP.

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* extension. It is deprecated and removed completely from PHP 7. Instead move on to MySQLi or PDO. Also, learn about Prepared Statements

Comment: Also learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Why `like` for an ID?

Comment: Please Show sample data

Comment: I think your Problem is solved if you replace: `product_id LIKE '%".$id."%'` with `product_id = $id'`

Comment: in inventory I. use like because inside my product_id. there's " 
6, 12, 34, 24, 23, 12, 3, 4" like this.

Comment: @Jens , what happen is that i only selected the last product_id from marias_products

Comment: **Never** store values as CSV in a database column!! Learn about normalization. For the meantime take a look into `find_in_set()`

Comment: Just last question @Jens. Why it only selected the last row. even i selected the specific primary key.

Comment: bacuse your code to print is outside of the while loop